# create two forms in one view

Tags: php, view, yii2

I used CRUD and I created two models. I tried to create two forms in one view. So in my controller I created new models and wrote a check if a form is filled to record it and if two forms to save two. But It not work for me. It is my controller actionCreate:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new UrUserForm();
    $userDate= new UserDataForm();
    $model->scenario = 'create';

     if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        try {
            $model->saveUser();
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', Yii::t('app', 'Dane nie zostały zapisane.'));
        }

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } elseif(($userDate->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))){
        try {
            var_dump( $model->saveUser(), $userDate->saveOptionalData());
            exit();
            $model->saveUser();
            $userDate->saveOptionalData();

        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', Yii::t('app', 'Dane nie zostały zapisane.'));
        }


} else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'userDate'=> $userDate
        ]);
}}
```

This var_dump is not displayed when i fill both forms. So i think i do some wrong in this controller. Maybe i show You My ModelsForm for sure

```
<?php

namespace backend\modules\users\models;

use common\models\User;
use backend\modules\users\models\UrUser;
use yii\base\Model;
use Yii;
use yii\helpers\Url;

/**
 * Signup form
 */
class UrUserForm extends Model {

    public $Login;
    public $Email;
    public $Password;
    public $Sex;
    public $Country;
    public $Language;
    public $Category;
    public $AccoutType;
    public $Name;
    public $Surname;
    public $BirthDate;
    public $RulesAccept;
    public $user;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['Country', 'Language', 'Category'], 'safe'],
            ['Login', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
            [['Login', 'Sex', 'Name', 'Surname', 'BirthDate'], 'required'],
            ['Login', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => Yii::t('app', 'Pdany login jest już używany')],
            ['Login', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],
            ['Email', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
            ['Email', 'required'],
            ['Email', 'email'],
            ['BirthDate', 'ageValidator'],
            ['Email', 'string', 'max' => 255],
            ['Email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => Yii::t('app', 'Podany e-mail jest już używany')],
            ['Password', 'string', 'min' => 6],
            ['Password', 'required','on' => 'create'],
        ];
    }

    public function saveUser() {

        $user = new UrUser();
        $user->Login = $this->Login;
        $user->Email = $this->Email;
        $user->RulesAccept = 1;
        $user->Rel_Sex = $this->Sex;
        $user->Name = $this->Name;
        $user->BirthDate = $this->BirthDate;
        $user->Surname = $this->Surname;
        $user->setPassword($this->Password);
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        $user->Rel_Country = $this->Country;
        $user->Rel_UserCategory = $this->Category;
        $user->Rel_Language = $this->Language;
        $user->status = 10;
        $this->user = $user;
        $user->created_at=time();
        if ($this->validate() && $user->validate()) {
            $user->save();
            return $user;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function updateUser() {
        $this->user->load($this->toArray(), '');
        $this->user->Rel_Country=$this->Country;
        $this->user->Rel_Language=$this->Language;
        $this->user->Rel_UserCategory=$this->Category;
        $this->user->Rel_Sex=$this->Sex;
        $this->user->updated_at=time();
        if (!empty($this->Password)) {
            $this->user->setPassword($this->Password);
        }

        return $this->user->save();
    }
```

And second model:

```
<?php
namespace backend\modules\users\models;

use common\models\UserData;
use frontend\modules\settings\models\Profile;

use yii\base\Model;
use Yii;
/**
 * Signup form
 */
class UserDataForm extends Model
{
    public $Address;
    public $NIP;
    public $CompanyName;
    public $Website;
    public $Phone;
    public $IsCompany;
    public $IsPhoneConfirmed;
    public $CreatedAt;
    public $UpdateAt;
    public $Rel_State;
    public $Rel_Currency;
    public $IsDeleted;
    public $Id;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */



    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['Address', 'Phone', 'Rel_State', 'Rel_Currency'], 'required'],
            [['NIP','Id', 'Phone', 'IsCompany', 'IsPhoneConfirmed', 'CreatedAt', 'UpdateAt', 'Rel_State', 'Rel_Currency', 'IsDeleted'], 'integer'],
            [['Address', 'CompanyName', 'Website'], 'string', 'max' => 45]
        ];
    }


     public function saveOptionalData() {

        $model = new UserData();
        //$user= 
        $model->Address=$this->Address;
        $model->Phone=$this->Phone;
        $model->Rel_State=$this->Rel_State;
        $model->Rel_Currency= $this->Rel_Currency;
        $model->NIP=$this->NIP;
        $model->IsCompany = $this->IsCompany;
        $model->IsPhoneConfirmed = $this->IsPhoneConfirmed;
        $model->CompanyName = $this->CompanyName;
        $model->Website = $this->Website;

        if ($this->validate() && $model->validate()) {
            //$user->Rel_RoyalUserData=$model->Id;
            $model->save();
            return $model;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Anyone can help me? I new in Yii but i tried to search for answer in documentation but i failed.

Answer (score 0):

Only one form can be submitted at any time. Each HTML form tag has its own action, even they can point to the same action URL, only one can be submitted at a time. You will have to put all the inputs in the same format if you would like to process them in one POST action.

Comment: how can I do in one form so that the data from the second model were optional, despite the fact that they have fields that are required. I do this so that the user can fill in the first part and save it and if you want it can also fill in additional data if they wish. But it is precisely in this second model are data that are required

Comment: can u look when u have time at my second model i need to do something if user dont want to fill optional data(second model) but in my this second model i have required rules

Comment: It is a little bit complicated. One way you may try is to stop Yii from generating client side validation rules by calling  `yii\widgets\ActiveField::$enableClientValidation` for the optional fields, and write your own client-side validation. For server side, can still simply use `$model->load()` and `$model->validate()`.

Comment: can u show me example please if you can in your free time on my code

Comment: or whem i do that in one form, then if userc click chcebox is organization then it show then scenraio with second model

Comment: This will do as well. If you refresh the page after clicking the checkbox, loading different scenario (one validating both models, another validating only one), it is even simpler. Can let Yii generate the UI, no need custom validation in this case.